# Does this result in a lock at execution time?

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, locking

I have this method here inside a WCF service call, that checks a `Dictionary` and then adds to it if there is no key present.  I create a `Delegate` inside a lock block, wondering if that would be a problem.

```
if (_delegates.ContainsKey(req.OperationName))
{
  return _delegates[req.OperationName](req);
}
else
{
lock (_syncRoot)
{
   if (_delegates.ContainsKey(req.OperationName) == false)
   {
     System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = GetType().GetMethod(req.OperationName, new Type[] { typeof(DataRequestContext) });
     if (mi != null)
     {
        InvokeDelegate d = new InvokeDelegate((r) => { return mi.Invoke(this, new object[] { r }); });
        _delegates.Add(req.OperationName, d);
     }
     else
     {
        throw new Exception("Unsupported operation: " + req.OperationName);
     }
}
  return _delegates[req.OperationName](req);
}
```

The code above is executed like this:

```
var del = GetDelegate( request);
del(request);
```

The first call will add to the Dictionary, subsequent calls will not need to add to the static Dictionary but the `Delegate` will be executed every time the code is run.

My brain says that this code segment will NOT block, am I correct?

```
        InvokeDelegate d = new InvokeDelegate((r) => { return mi.Invoke(this, new object[] { r }); });
```

I cannot test it and generate the lock condition so I need to ask:

The code that actually gets executed in the real world scenario is below, the parameter `req` is an object that contains runtime values I use to execute:

```
public AES.Cloud.Common.DataDictionary GetConditionAndItems(AES.Cloud.Common.DataRequestContext req)
    {
        List<ConditionItem> items = null;
        List<MiscItem> miscitems = null;
        var cond = GetConditionAndItems(req.GetValue<Guid>("conditionId"), out items, out miscitems);
        AES.Cloud.Common.DataDictionary dd = new Common.DataDictionary();
        dd.AddList("items", items);
        dd.AddList("miscItems", miscitems);
        dd.AddObject("Condition", cond);
        return dd;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any evidence that you're dealing with more than one thread here...so why would it lock?

Comment: because it is called every time my WCF service is executed.

Comment: You made absolutely no mention that WCF was involved here.  Did you think we'd infer that?

Comment: does it really matter?  multiple threads will execute this code, that is all that matters.

Comment: Of course it matters...you didn't (and still don't) show how and even if multiple threads are running this code.  You need to create a [mcve].

Comment: Show us the code or the documentation for `InvokeDelegate` , what it does with the passed in delegate matters.

Comment: Unrelated question: why throw System.Exception instead of a more specific exception?

Comment: @rory.ap, the code gets executed 8000 per minute from different clients.

Answer (score 2):

Any thread reaching a `lock` statement will wait for any existing locks (on the same object) to be released before executing the code within the lock.

If your code that invokes the delegate is not encapsulated within a lock, it will not await a lock release to execute..

Comment: I know that, my question is about the Delegate, the delegate doesn't execute until after this method

Comment: that is what I am thinking...  change your answer...  even tho it seems more of an opinion.